# Is it possible to export eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse

I have installed Eclipse IDE in my desktop. I have installed additional plugins in it.

Is it possible to export this IDE, so that I can use it on another machine without requiring to install the plugins again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse is very easy to replicate : just copy/paste the entire Eclipse folder.

You might need to grab workspace-specific files too. In that case, you can also copy/paste the `.metadata` folder of your workspace. It's best to run the `eclipse -clean` command just before copying it though.

Finally, don't forget you can export your preferences : `File->Export->General->Preferences`